# How to minimise food spitting from sneezing

Tags: food, personal-care, comfort

I experience this embarrassing scenario of sneezing while my mouth is full with food, and it has been happening again quite often recently(Well count myself unlucky, even when I took a friend's advice on eating slower, in those few times where I just happen to go overboard with my speed, it just happens and I get into a mess). It always comes at the most unpredictable moment and my sneeze gives me very little reaction time to do anything with whatever is in my mouth. Usually, I will just turn away from everyone, cover my nose and mouth in hope of minimizing the food that gets thrown out from either place and landing onto someone.

However, my past actions only prevented others from being affected by my actions. It does no value in preventing the sneeze or minimizing food that is spit out.

Sometimes, the consequences of sneezing may lead to an irritated nose if it happens that any spicy food that I was currently eating was thrown out mostly from my nose.

In such a short reaction time and with high surprise element where it’s difficult to either swallow and spit out the food immediately, is there any solution anyone can recommend to achieve the goal of preventing the sneezing or minimizing food that is spit out. I have seen some of these posts [here](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/13825/how-to-avoid-a-loud-embarrassing-sneeze) and [here](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/6377/i-cant-stop-sneezing), but I'm not sure if they actually work or they really solve my problem here. Thanks.

Comment: Does it happen more with foods containing particular spices/ingredients?

Comment: @CaiusJard I think it does, but I'm not fully aware of the culprit ingredients of the food that caused this. It happens quite randomly really, like even just eating plain noodles.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid unnecessary loss of food, breathe out through your nose and attempt to empty lungs completely of air quickly, and most food will remain in mouth, if not all. Try not to eat too fast.

Jatt

Comment: So you are suggesting sneezing with your mouth closed?  Whenever I've seen people try this, some food comes out of their nose.

Comment: @Chenmunka and food lodged in one's sinuses can be very painful! However, what Jatt suggests is to breath all of your air out just before, minimizing the amount of air forced out by the sneeze.